# SQL two where conditions not working?

Tags: sql, ionic2

I am trying to run this part of code

```
"UPDATE savedPosts SET liked = 1 WHERE liked <> 1 AND id ='" + idVar + "'"
```

If I take away the first where condition it works as expected. If I then add the where condition that checks if liked is not equal to 1 it still returns a success. And this always. I dont get it... If 'liked' is set to 1 how can this query be successfull on the second run? And I see it in my db that liked is set to 1 after the first query.

I want different messages shown on the screen for a success and error message. Please help because I tried everything like:

```
"UPDATE savedPosts SET liked = 1 WHERE (liked <> 1 AND id ='" + idVar + "')"
"UPDATE savedPosts SET liked = 1 WHERE 'liked' <> 1 AND 'id' ='" + idVar + "'"
```

And variations of both

EDIT

```
this.storage.query("UPDATE savedPosts SET liked = 1 WHERE liked <> 1 AND id ='" + idVar + "'").then((data) => {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(data.res));
                }, (error) => {
                    console.log("ERROR -> " + JSON.stringify(error.err));
                });
```

Comment: Updating zero rows is still a success. This is 100% normal. you're probably more interested in checking the number of affected rows.

Comment: @sstan Only 1 row can be affected at a time due to the id condition. I want to use different snackbars depending if the row is already updated to 1 or not. Do I have to use a select query befor or is it possible to do so in one query?

Comment: what do you mean by different snackbars ?? Please elaborate your issue with some example

Comment: Like I mentioned in my comment, when you run the update statement, you'll want to check how many rows were updated. If the returned value is zero, then you can choose to throw an error.  If you show us how you run the SQL, is it JDBC? ADO.NET? Other?  Then we can show you how to get that information.

Comment: @Ravi Just a prompt like an alert

Comment: That's UI part. right ? That's you have to figure out how will you show alert. That again depend which programming language are you using for your UI development

Comment: @sstan I just edited the complete query and I am using Ionic2 with their sqlStorage

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not familiar with Ionic2. Maybe someone else can help? Normally, I would expect `this.storage.query(sql)` to somehow be able to return how many rows were affected by the SQL statement.  Maybe Ionic2 doesn't support that.  If so, you may have to check the data with a `select` query first before updating the data, just as you had suggested in a previous comment.